# Mongoose query on subdocument returns array of other subdocument using projection

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

**Update:** I am looking for an answer that works within mongodb projection: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#definition

I am trying to filter a query on a subdocument using projection so that it only returns a specific array. But when filtering the result also includes an array of another subdocument. When I don't filter it only returns the found document.

I tried different filtering options including and excluding positional elements, but can't get the desired return.

**Mongoose schema**

```
const stationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  mac: String,
  stationName: String,
  syncReadings: Boolean,
  temperature: Array,
  humidity: Array,
  measures: [{
  date: Date,
  temperature: Number,
  humidity: Number
  }],
  lastUpdated: Date

});

// Define user schema
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String
    },
    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        name         : String,
        email        : String
    },
    twitter          : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        displayName  : String,
        username     : String
   },
   google           : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
   },
   apiKey: String,
   stations : [stationSchema]

   },  
   {
       usePushEach: true 
   }
);
```

**Api handler**

```
app.get('/api/stations/:stationName/measures', function(req, res, next) {

  var user = {
    apiKey: req.user.apiKey
  }

  const query = {
        apiKey: user.apiKey,
        stations.stationName': req.params.stationName
  }

  const options = {
        'stations.measures': 1
  }

  User.findOne(query, options)
  .exec()
  .then(stations => {       
        res.status(200).send(stations)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
  })

});
```

There are two stations under one user:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5c39c99356bbf002fb092ce9",
        "stations": [
            {
                "stationName": "livingroom",
                "mac": "5C:CF:7F:77:12:FB",
                "_id": "5c39c9ab56bbf002fb092cea",
                "lastUpdated": "2019-01-12T11:07:01.802Z",
                "syncReadings": false,
                "measures": [],
                "humidity": [],
                "temperature": [
                    {
                        "date": "2019-01-12T11:07:01.802Z",
                        "temperature": "20"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "stationName": "office",
                "mac": "5C:CF:7F:77:12:FC",
                "_id": "5c39cacdce4ac903123f0150",
                "measures": [],
                "humidity": [],
                "temperature": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**API call**

```
http://localhost:8080/api/stations/livingroom/measures
```

**Result**

```
{
    "_id": "5c39c99356bbf002fb092ce9",
    "stations": [
        {
            "measures": []
        },
        {
            "measures": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**Projection options tried**

```
 const options = {
   'stations.measures': 1
 }

 const options = {
   'stations.$.measures': 1
 }

 const options = {
   'stations.$': 1,
   'stations.$.measures': 1
 }

 const options = {
   'stations.$': 1,
   'stations.measures': 1
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try using these querying params only and after that you will get a user with a requested station..

```
var user = {
    apiKey: req.user.apiKey
  }

  const query = {
        apiKey: user.apiKey,
        'stations.stationName': req.params.stationName
  }
```

then do this

```
    User.findOne(query, options)
      .exec()
      .then(stations => {      

        for(let station of stations){
           if(station.measures[1]){ // here it is the index  

           res.status(200).send(stations);
        }
    }


})
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
  })
```

actually in mongoose you cannot query sub-sub documents to you will have to you this approach.. You can only query sub docs only like you have done

Comment: Hi! When using dot notation in queries you need to use quotation marks right? The typo was a missing quotation mark. So this doesn't solve the wrong array that is returned.

If you query on stationName as well, you can use the $ selector to get the index of a subdocument. And I also use the api key so that you can't post to a station of someone else.

But maybe I'm wrong!

Comment: it seem to me that you are working on a project with arduino am I right ? if so let me know coz I think you know your way around how to make post and get req to a node server . I currently am in need of a way to implement a fingerprint scanner using arduino and check users with node js mongo db back end

Comment: Without the quotation marks, I get this error in terminal:

/Users/markdegroot/Desktop/dev/homeweather/controllers/api/api.js:132
        stations.stationName: req.params.stationName
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: Yes, I am making a dashboard environment for temperature and humidity: 
Git: https://github.com/msnederland/homeweather

website: http://homeweather.nl

Comment: Yes, and you should be able to select the array within the findOne() method.

Comment: so what you are saying is the problem is in you findOne method right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Look here at Projection: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#definition

Comment: try this post - https://coderwall.com/p/6v5rcw/querying-sub-documents-and-sub-sub-documents-in-mongoose

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this post and it would be a workaround, but I was looking for an answer that works within mongodb native functions. It is in their docs that you should be able to do it with projections.